# Multidex Error на Android 5 (LG G4c)

Tags: java, android, gradle, twitter, multidex

Не могу найти ошибку, чтобы её исправить/погуглить. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Работает на 6х версиях(sony z3c),на 4.4 версиях (samsung s3), на эмуляторе 7.0.1.

**Не работает на 5 версии**

Грешу на Multidex, так как я отлавливаю ошибку, где ругается в логах, а примерно такая же появляется в другом месте..

Лог:

```
    E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;
      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuthService.<init>(OAuthService.java:56)
      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth2Service.<init>(OAuth2Service.java:59)
      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.createGuestSessionProvider(TwitterCore.java:223)
      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.getGuestSessionProvider(TwitterCore.java:216)
      at com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetComposer.onPreExecute(TweetComposer.java:72)
      at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
      at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
      at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
      at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
      at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:439)
      at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:383)
      at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:341)
      at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:312)
      at ru.test.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:64)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4648)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuthService.<init>(OAuthService.java:56) 
                                                                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth2Service.<init>(OAuth2Service.java:59) 
                                                                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.createGuestSessionProvider(TwitterCore.java:223) 
                                                                at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.getGuestSessionProvider(TwitterCore.java:216) 
                                                                at com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetComposer.onPreExecute(TweetComposer.java:72) 
                                                                at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44) 
                                                                at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611) 
                                                                at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43) 
                                                                at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69) 
                                                                at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:439) 
                                                                at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:383) 
                                                                at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:341) 
                                                                at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:312) 
                                                                at ru.test.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:64) 
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4648) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder
                                                                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                        ... 26 more
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Ругается на вторую строку:

```
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

Файл app/build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.0'
}
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: 'blade'
    android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}

dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ru.test.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.2"
    multiDexEnabled  true

}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false

    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}


}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':vksdk_library')
/*compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}*/
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-core-parent:1.4.14'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'

compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.1'
compile 'com.githang:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2@aar'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick:2.3.6'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.linwoain.library:library:1.0'
compile 'io.apptik.widget:multislider:1.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'ru.ok:odnoklassniki-android-sdk:2.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
provided 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick-processor:2.3.6'
provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
//compile 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Класс Application, где есть инициализация multidex:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

// Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "xxxx";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "xxxx";

private static Context context;

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return Application.context;
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Application.context = getApplicationContext();
    VKSdk.initialize(getApplicationContext());

    String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());

    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "ru.test.app",  // replace with your unique package name
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            Log.d("TAG_FACEBOOK", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE1**

**ЮрийСПб**

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'` не даёт закомитить, она используется. Поэтому закомитил только `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'`

В итоге лог немного изменился

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: ru.test.app, PID: 10026
                                                         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuthService.<init>(OAuthService.java:56)
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth2Service.<init>(OAuth2Service.java:59)
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.createGuestSessionProvider(TwitterCore.java:223)
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.getGuestSessionProvider(TwitterCore.java:216)
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetComposer.onPreExecute(TweetComposer.java:72)
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:439)
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:383)
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:341)
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:312)
                                                             at ru.test.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:64)
                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ru.test.app-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                             at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuthService.<init>(OAuthService.java:56) 
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth2Service.<init>(OAuth2Service.java:59) 
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.createGuestSessionProvider(TwitterCore.java:223) 
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.getGuestSessionProvider(TwitterCore.java:216) 
                                                             at com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetComposer.onPreExecute(TweetComposer.java:72) 
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44) 
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611) 
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43) 
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69) 
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:439) 
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:383) 
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:341) 
                                                             at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:312) 
                                                             at ru.test.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:64) 
                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339) 
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder
                                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                    ... 26 more
                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
    03-25 08:56:24.106 10026-10111/ru.test.app E/FirebaseCrash: Error sending crash report
                                                        bmk: Server did not receive report: Origin Error message: Requests from this Android client application ru.test.app are blocked.
                                                            at bmu.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1053)
                                                            at bna.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:5055)
                                                            at bna.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:54)
                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

      03-25 08:56:33.457 10026-10095/ru.test.app W/Fabric: Could not call getId on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info

      03-25 08:56:33.463 10026-10095/ru.test.app W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

      03-25 08:56:33.464 10026-10095/ru.test.app W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

      03-25 08:56:43.470 10026-10095/ru.test.app W/Fabric: Could not call isLimitAdTrackingEnabled on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 2**

**ЮрийСПб**, да Вы, дяденька - волшебник)

Последовал Вашему совету и почистил импорты от чредующихся библиотек и заработало!

В итоге так:

```
dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':vksdk_library')
/*compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}*/
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'

compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-core-parent:1.4.14'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14'

//compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'  // это закоммитил
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0' //это пришлось оставить

// ЮрийСПб дал эти строки////////////////////////////////
//Retrofit
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
//OkHttp
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
// ЮрийСПб дал эти строки/////////////////////////////////

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick:2.3.6'
provided 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick-processor:2.3.6'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

compile 'com.githang:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.linwoain.library:library:1.0'
compile 'io.apptik.widget:multislider:1.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'ru.ok:odnoklassniki-android-sdk:2.0.2'

provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

//закоммитил то, что по моему мнению дублирует импорты ниже
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
//compile 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.3'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас анархия в зависимостях. Постарайтесь сгруппировать их чтобы было легче в них разобраться. Проверьте их на актуальные версии. Скорее всего именно в этом и проблема - у вас старый `Retrofit`, а он в себе содержит либу `OkHttp` на отсутствие классов коей и намекает выдача логов. Попробуйте вот это

> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
>
> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'

заменить этим:

```
//Retrofit
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
//OkHttp
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
```

Comment: а разве так может быть,  что из за этого не работает, но на 4й и 6й версиях работает?

Comment: @zayn1991, мне кажется что да, но пока вы не проверите мы точно не узнаем)

Comment: обновил вопрос (UPDATE1) с вашим решением. Всё ещё ругается на ту же строку кода

Comment: ответ в **обновление2**